# A timer seems to run faster when using classes. In a C version, it works as expected

Tags: c++, timer, arduino

A timer in Arduino seems to run faster when using classes. But in a C version (with the same values), it works as expected.

1. I coded a quick and dirty version for a NEC infrared protocol decoder on Arduino UNO (kind of plain C, no classes). It worked.
2. I coded a class in C++ (encapsulating data) for the same problem, but  Timer1 seems to run a lot faster. In the C version I got 13500 microseconds for a run, which is Ok and expected. In the C++ version I got 5 microseconds. It makes no sense.
3. I rewrite the C version in a module (*.cpp and *.h; though it's cpp I'm not using classes) and it still worked.

The ISRs runs in both C and C++, but for a unknown reason the Timer1 runs faster, or it's not running whatsoever.

```
// C version of the initializer function:
void ir_init(  IR_Nek* self, uint8_t pin, uint8_t address )
{
    self->pin = pin;
    self->address = address;

    self->bits = 0;
    self->error = false;
    self->done = false;

    TCCR1A = 0;
    TCCR1B = 0;                                    
    TCNT1  = 0;                                    
    TIMSK1 = 1;                                    

    pinMode( self->pin, INPUT );
}


// C version of the NEC core decoder:
void ir_decode_isr( IR_Nek* self )
{
    static uint8_t state = 0;
    static uint8_t bit_counter = 0;
    uint16_t period = 0;

    digitalWrite( 13, HIGH );

    switch( state ){

        case 0:
            self->error = false;

            TCNT1 = 0;
            TCCR1B = 2;
            state = 1;

            break;

        case 1:
            period = TCNT1 >> 1;
            TCNT1 = 0;

            if( 13000 < period and period < 14000 ){
                state = 2;
                self->done = false;
                bit_counter = 32;
                self->bits = 0L;
            } else{
                state = 0;
                self->error = true;
                TCCR1B = 0;
            }
            break;

        case 2:
        {

            period = TCNT1 >> 1;
            TCNT1 = 0;

            uint8_t bit_val;
            if( 1000 < period and period < 1300 ){
                bit_val = 0;
            } else if( 2100 < period and period < 2400 ){
                bit_val = 1;
            } else{
                state = 0;
                self->error = true;
                TCCR1B = 0;
            }

            self->bits |= bit_val ? 0x00000001 : 0x00000000;
            if( bit_counter > 1 ) self->bits <<= 1;

            --bit_counter;
            if( bit_counter == 0 ){
                TCCR1B = 0;
                state = 0;
                self->error = false;
                self->done = true;
            }

            break;
        }

        default:
            TCCR1B = 0;
            state = 0;
            self->done = false;
            self->error = true;
            break;

    } // switch

    digitalWrite( 13, LOW );
}


// C++ constructor:
IR_Nek::IR_Nek( uint8_t pin, uint8_t address ) :
    pin{pin}, address{address}
{
    this->bits = 0;
    this->error = false;
    this->done = false;

    TCCR1A = 0;
    TCCR1B = 0;                                    
    TCNT1  = 0;                                    
    TIMSK1 = 1;                                    

    pinMode( this->pin, INPUT );
}


// C++ version of the NEC core decoder
void IR_Nek::decode_isr()
{
    static uint8_t state = 0;
    static uint8_t bit_counter = 0;
    uint16_t period = 0;

    switch( state ){

        case 0:
            this->error = false;

            TCNT1 = 0;
            TCCR1B = 2;
            state = 1;

            break;

        case 1:
            period = TCNT1 >> 1;
            TCNT1 = 0;

            if( 13000 < period and period < 14000 ){
                state = 2;
                this->done = false;
                bit_counter = 32;
                this->bits = 0L;
            } else{
                state = 0;
                this->error = true;
                TCCR1B = 0;
            }
            break;

        case 2:
        {

            period = TCNT1 >> 1;
            TCNT1 = 0;

            uint8_t bit_val;
            if( 1000 < period and period < 1300 ){
                bit_val = 0;
            } else if( 2100 < period and period < 2400 ){
                bit_val = 1;
            } else{
                state = 0;
                this->error = true;
                TCCR1B = 0;
            }

            this->bits |= bit_val ? 0x00000001 : 0x00000000;
            if( bit_counter > 1 ) this->bits <<= 1;

            --bit_counter;
            if( bit_counter == 0 ){
                TCCR1B = 0;
                state = 0;
                this->error = false;
                this->done = true;
            }

            break;
        }

        default:
            TCCR1B = 0;
            state = 0;
            this->done = false;
            this->error = true;
            break;

    } // switch
}
```

I expect something between 13000 and 14000 microseconds, but I get 5.

Comment: *but for a unknown reason* -- Using Occam's razor, the reason is more than likely you implemented the C++ version differently than the C version, so much different in that the logic flow is different.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it took me many years to stop blaming my tools even when I knew chances were 99% likely that it was a mistake of mine that was causing a bug.

Comment: "Unknown reason" is a way of speaking, which in turns translates to "I have no idea what's going on". I'm using the same values for the timer initialization in both versions, so I'm expecting to get the same results, but <I don't have the slightest idea> in which ways the hardware might missbehave when in C++.

Comment: You need to learn more about the hardware then, because the problem almost certainly doesn't originate with C++.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Arduino, but I'm going to guess the difference is because you call `digitalWrite( 13, HIGH );` at the top of `ir_decode_dsr()`, but neglect to do so at the top of `IR_Nek::decode_isr()`.

Comment: Also see: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/digitalwrite/

Comment: I'm not using the LED on pin 13 to monitor de ellapsed time; instead, I do print the value of the period variable. In the C version it gives a very close value of 13500 microseconds; however, in the C++ version I'm getting 5 microseconds. If using an oscilloscope, the ISR tooks roughly 8 microseconds.